# change UICollectionView cell's alpha value not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to tap the cell of the UICollectionView and the cell becomes half transparent.

```
    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GLEpisodeCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[GLEpisodeCell identifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];//GLEpisodeCell is subclass of UICollectionViewCell
    cell.alpha=0.5;
    cell.contentView.alpha=0.5;
}
```

But this doesn't work. The cell is still opacity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this it might help you.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GLEpisodeCell *cell=[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];//GLEpisodeCell is subclass of UICollectionViewCell
    cell.alpha=0.5;
    cell.contentView.alpha=0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I make a low-grade mistake.

Answer (score 4):

The layout sets the alpha. To override, place this in your cell subclass:

```
override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    alpha = 0.5
}
```

You will also have to set the alpha for newly created cells.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.5];`

This will create the cell's background colour as 50% transperant NOT the contents of the cell as well.If you want that then you want.
`cell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.5;`

Comment: check if you are catching the right cell by changing the background color to red or something.. notice the change.